# Where Do I Redeem My Familiar Ticket?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

As a pre-order bonus I have a **Flutterby Ticket** in my inventory.

Where do I go to redeem this for the familiar?  I can't just use it out of my intenvory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it at Solomon's castle as well, just talk to Solomon

Comment: Confirmed. This occurs earlier in the game than the Pandora League so it seems more appropriate as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you open the Pandora League, you will be able to access the Elemental Shrine there, and then you will be able to redeem your ticket and receive your familiar.

Comment: At what point in the game does that happen?  Is it something after the main story?